# Regex to match a single character or an escaped character

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write my own `Format` code for time, this is a class project but the `Format` is an added for myself to work more with C# Regex. So what I am trying to do is match certain characters.

```
W w : w = weeks. W weeks preceded by a leading zero if smaller than 10
D d : d = days. D days preceded by a leading zero if smaller than 10
G g : g = Military Hours: G hours preceded by a leading zero if smaller than 10
H h : h = Civilian Hours: H hours preceded by a leading zero...
m : m = minutes
s : s = seconds
```

So what I have the regex so far is this

```
(w|W)(?=\b)|(d|D)(?=\b)|(h|H|g|G)(?=\b)|(m)(?=\b)|(s)(?=\b)

(w|W) //match upper or lower W
(?=\b) //positive lookahead only match if not apart of a word boundary
```

With the s it's match all `s` in the string so I'm lead to believe my regex is wrong of course.
My problem is that I'm not sure how to do lookaheads and lookbehinds correctly. I basically only want the cases of characters I've supplied and only if they are by themselves OR escaped see examples below.

```
Format("w Weeks, D days, h:m:s");
//returns 7 Weeks, 04 days, 10:01:05
Format("[w] weeks [d] days H:m:s");
//returns [7] weeks [4] days 10:01:05
Format("w \Weeks D \days, h:m:s");
//returns 7 07eeks 04 4ays, 10:01:05
```

As you can see the last format with escaped w's and d's it still replaces them. Which is what I want. Again I'm not sure how to write the lookaheads and lookbehinds correctly .

I am using https://regex101.com/r/sL9cI2/1  regex101 here to test on. You can see it and what is going on. any suggestions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing about [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) is that they match **an empty string**. `\b` matches a position, not a character, where it has a *[word character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)* on one side, and it doesn't have a *[word character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)* on the other. Eg, in `"This is an example"`, there are 8 positions matching `\b`:

```
|This| |is| |an| |example|

| ::: denotes a word boundary
```

To match words, the regex should check it has a word boundary on each side: `\bword\b` (Notice there's no need for lookaheads here).

> I basically only want the cases of characters I've supplied and only if they are by themselves OR escaped

Then you have 2 options to match:

1. `\bw\b` The letter "w" as a word.
2. `\\w` a backslash (you need to escape backslashes in regex) followed by the letter w.

Regex:

```
(\bw\b|\\w)
```

Moreover, looking at your attempts, I think you can use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to simplify the pattern.

---

**Regex:**

```
(\b[WwDdGgHhms]\b|\\[WwDdGgHhms])
```

<kbd>[regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sL9cI2/3)</kbd>

- Do note that this regex does not validate consecutive backslashes, which means we can't reliably specify a backslash in front of format code.

  Using `\\week` as an example, it is interpreted as `\` followed by week format code then literal string `eek`, instead of literal `\` followed by literal string `week`.

Use the following regex if you want to support such use case:

```
\G(?:[^\\]|\\.)*?(\b[WwDdGgHhms]\b|\\[WwDdGgHhms])
```

<kbd>[regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sL9cI2/4)</kbd>

Comment: Ok so now that you've explained the word boundary to me I understand them a bit better. I'm reading on them and I though `word` was a word boundary. And I should have used the character class from the get go -_- right over my head to be honest. So that takes the need from lookarounds! Thank you Mariano!

Comment: Matching `\\[WwDdGgHhms]` is going to run into the problem where you can't tell whether ``\`` is part of previous escape, or is escaping the next character. Consider the input `\\w` (backslash followed by w format code) versus `\w` (escape w - literal w).

Comment: @nhahtdh That's described in the answer as `this regex does not validate consecutive backslashes`. I prefered to keep things simple, since it wasn't specified in the question. If needed, use this pattern to prevent that case https://regex101.com/r/sL9cI2/4